# Como chamar um objecto dentro da criação de outro objecto

Tags: java, classes, objetos

Tenho uma classe Pessoa e uma Classe Data, a classe Pessoa cria uma pessoa a classe data cria uma data para usar como data de nascimento na classe Pessoa, como é que ao criar uma Pessoa crio uma data sem ter que usar o codigo completo no meio do objecto pessoa, o codigo criado até agora é este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data d = new Data(0, 0, 0);
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa("Miguel", "Rua D. Maria", "7400604", objeto_data, "Solteiro");

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possivel criar a data direto no comando, conforme o código abaixo:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa("Miguel", "Rua D. Maria", "7400604", new Data(0, 0, 0), "Solteiro");
```

Ou criar esta data no construtor da classe Pessoa.

Comment: ok era mesmo isso que eu me estava a esquecer, assim não preciso de criar a referencia ?

Comment: O comando `new` cria a referencia e passa direto para o metodo. Dessa forma nao precisa criar a variavel